# Enzyme testing error with find()

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, chai, material-ui, enzyme

I try find and testing MUI component inside mine component, and receive the error
 "before each" hook for "should render ":
Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {props}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.

```
import FloatingActionButton from 'material-ui/FloatingActionButton'

import IconButton from '../../src/IconButton'

describe.only('<IconButton/>', () => {
    let iconButton, props
    beforeEach(() => {
        iconButton = shallow(<IconButton />).find(FloatingActionButton)
        // console.log(iconButton.node.type)
        props = iconButton.props()
    })
```

Component itself

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import FloatingActionButton from 'material-ui/FloatingActionButton'

import getStyle from './styles'
import '../styles/buttons.scss'

const IconButton = ({color = 'normal', ...props}) =>
    <FloatingActionButton
        disableTouchRipple
        mini
        zDepth={1}
        {...props}
        {...getStyle(color, props.disabled, props.children)}
    />

IconButton.propTypes = {
    color: PropTypes.string,
    icon: PropTypes.node,
    children: PropTypes.node,
    disabled: PropTypes.bool,
    // here we must use object proptype as style is an object and there is no validation for style type
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/forbid-prop-types
    style: PropTypes.object,
}

export default IconButton
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with enzyme but with React rendering. Show your FloatingActionButton the error cause seems to be there.

Comment: Are you exporting the components correctly?

Comment: @CharlieBrown the FloatingActionButton is material ui component, do you thing the problem with rendering this component?

Comment: @MartinDawson also when try console.log(iconButton.node) - I see this component as node 
```.{ '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
  type:
   { [Function: FloatingActionButton]
     defaultProps: { disabled: false, mini: false, secondary: false, zDepth: 2 },
     contextTypes: { muiTheme: [Function: bound checkType] },```